# My UIScrollView works bad (when the keyboard appears)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, keyboard

I have little problem in my app. I have a UIScrollView with many text fields, everything works fine, but when I click on one of the text field, I can (manually) to scroll beyond the boundaries of my scroller. I enclose code and an image of my problem. **I need to stop scrolling (when I editing one of the others text field) under the last text field.**

```
#import "CervenaViewController.h"

@interface CervenaViewController ()

@end

@implementation CervenaViewController

@synthesize pocetHodinTextField, pocetMinutTextField, pocetSekundTextField, pocetDniTextField, pocetTydnuTextField, pocetLetTextField, pocetMesicuTextField, pocetMilisekundTextField, pocetMikrosekundTextField, pocetNanosekundTextField, pocetPikosekundTextField;

@synthesize activeTextField;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"modry.jpg"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];

    if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height<568)
    {
        NSLog(@"3.5 inch screen");
        [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,1120)];

    }
    else
    {
        [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,1040)];
    }
    pocetLetTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
    pocetMesicuTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
    pocetTydnuTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
    pocetDniTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
    pocetHodinTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
    pocetMinutTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
    pocetSekundTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
    pocetMilisekundTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
    pocetMikrosekundTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
    pocetNanosekundTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
    pocetPikosekundTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    // Step 1: Get the size of the keyboard.
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;


    // Step 2: Adjust the bottom content inset of your scroll view by the keyboard height.
    if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height<568)
    {
        NSLog(@"3.5 inch screen");
        UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 0.0);
        scroller.contentInset = contentInsets;
        scroller.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    }
    else
    {
        UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 500.0, 0.0);
         scroller.contentInset = contentInsets;
         scroller.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    }

    // Step 3: Scroll the target text field into view.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint) 
    {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,  self.activeTextField.frame.origin.y);
        [scroller setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scroller.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scroller.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.activeTextField = textField;
    activeTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;

}

// Set activeTextField to nil

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.activeTextField = nil;
}
```

Update: OK I fix it. You can delete this Question. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Set the content offset your scrollview properly.

For better understanding take a look at below git.
You could directly use this code, which will resolved your issue.

Take a look at this [Git, for the scroll view](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding/blob/master/TPKeyboardAvoiding/TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.m)